# How to pass unbound multidimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any way to pass a multidimensional array to a function without knowing the no of columns.... I mean say I want to print a multidimensional array say `a[][9]` and `b[][3]`. If I make a common function say print.

```
// I have to specify the no of columns right and since
// the no of columns should be same for both actual and
// formal arguments
void print(int a[][])
```

I have to make different functions for different multidimensional arrays. There should be some way around it.

How to pass unbound multidimensional array?

Comment: using a native array, no there isn't. An array must know the stride of the element type, and in an array of arrays, the element type is the inferior array. Thus its magnitude must be known. If you want to do this, you need to use a pointer array (they're *not* the same). Or use a **VLA** (variable length array) if your toolchain supports it (most do). Either way, you need to know the dimension limits one way or another).

Comment: would u tell me how do i use a pointer to print ..... i suppose u are speaking of passing the adress of first element and print the rest in a nested loop .... i thot of it .

Comment: As I said, at-most one dimension (the most superior) of a native array can be without bound. Even then to avoid overrun you must have *some* way of determining maximum bound of the unbound dimension. The most logical mechanism for what you seek is a construct such as a VLA as described in Matt's answer, or a linear mapping as described in Jonathan's answer. **Either way, you *have* to know the dimensions of what you seek to output.** There is no escaping that fact. Their proposals allow you to submit those magnitudes at *runtime* rather than compile time, which should provide what you seek.

Comment: oh ohk...thank you guys a lot ! i am creating a sudoku solver....im in the learning process so ....i am no expert in these so if my doubhts were silly im sorry...and i do know the second dimension should always be specified.... and i thnk ill go with the VLA ....nyway thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to include all of the array dimensions, except the innermost one (although you probably do want to give the innermost one anyway, so that your function knows when to stop printing). If the dimension is not known at compile time then you can make it a parameter to the function:

```
void print(size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n])
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i )
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j )
             printf("%d\n", a[i][j]);
}
```

Calling the function:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[][4] = { { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, {8, 7, 6, 5}, {11, 10, 12, 9} };
    print(3, 4, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, and in case it wasn't obvious to the OP, this was the VLA method I referred to in general-comment. Nice answer.

Comment: the problem here is that .....suppose i create a header and give the function prototype.. i have to specify the dimension there right...so it wont work or would it?? like if prototype is void print(int m,int n,//here i would have to specify the dimension) and if the n i passed doesnt match with the limit in prototype ..it would be an error right?

Comment: The prototype for the function would be `void print(size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n]);` and you are allowed to pass any shape of array to that function as long as you specify the dimension values before the array itself, as shown.  No; there wouldn't be a problem with `int a1[4][44] = { ... }; print(4, 44, a1); int a2[100][20] = { ... }; print(100, 20, a2);`.  Both are conformant calls to the `print` function.

Comment: @prabhakartp read the error messages... you have to include a standard header to get `size_t`, for example `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`

Comment: If you don't need the file I/O functions that are in `<stdio.h>` or general code that's in `<stdlib.h>`, use `<stddef.h>` to declare `size_t`; it is the smallest and simplest of the headers that does define `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

[Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830598) shows how to use the C99 or C11 variable-length array facilities.  There is an alternative that will work with C89 too (which might be a factor if you code on Windows with MSVC), but you still have to tell the function about both dimensions of the array, and you have to do the subscript calculations yourself:

```
void print(size_t m, size_t n, int *a)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf(" %d", a[i * n + j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

You might call this as:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[][4] = { { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, {8, 7, 6, 5}, {11, 10, 12, 9} };
    print(3, 4, &a[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
 0 1 2 3
 8 7 6 5
 11 10 12 9
```

*(One minor comment: I'm not certain that the automatic array could be initialized like that in C89 — there were some restrictions still on automatic variable initialization.  If it doesn't work, simply move the entire array declaration outside of `main()` and prefix it with `static` so it becomes a file scope array.)*

Comment: hey thank you.....this works...bt prinitng was just an example .... i needed an alternative way...i already coded my program a lot when i came across this problem.... so if i change it to pointer arithmetics its a very troublesome job cus i would have to change a lot of functions and expressions.... is there any other way ? and thanks a lot !!! i just need the function to accept any dimensional multidimensional array....i searched the net and came across **a (pointer to pointer) how does it work ??

Comment: Using `int **` requires a lot more care in the setup of the data; you need an array of pointers as well as the (2D) array of `int` values.  The code you wrote doesn't work as written, so you're going to have to fix it somehow.  If you can use the C99 VLA notation, do so; it is neater.  Only if you're stuck with C89 should you consider using what I suggest.

Comment: oh ohk....ill go with the VLA method and i guess ill have to change my code..and thanks a lot for the help :)